# How to build React Styleguidist with Tailwind CSS using CRACO Webpack config?

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, tailwind-css, react-styleguidist, craco

As specified in their [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app), using Tailwind CSS with CRA (create-react-app) requires replacing `react-scripts` with `craco`.

Now, I'm trying to build a component library using React Styleguidist. I was able to get Tailwind CSS to display correctly in localhost when running `styleguidist server` by specifying in the `styleguide.config.js` to use the craco webpack config file in  with craco's API like so

```js
/* styleguide.config.js */
const path = require('path')
    
const { createWebpackDevConfig } = require("@craco/craco");
    
const cracoConfig = require("./craco.config.js");
const webpackConfig = createWebpackDevConfig(cracoConfig);
    
module.exports = {
  webpackConfig,
  require: [
    path.join(__dirname, './src/styles/tailwind.css')
  ]
}
```

However, when I try to build the production HTML using `styleguidist build`, it throws these errors

```
 Building style guide...
 FAIL  Failed to compile

./src/components/atoms/Button/index.js
Error: [BABEL] /Users/vivz753/react-components/src/components/atoms/Button/index.js: React Refresh Babel transform should only be enabled in development environment. Instead, the environment is: "production". If you want to override this check, pass {skipEnvCheck: true} as plugin options. (While processing: "/Users/vivz753/react-components/node_modules/react-refresh/babel.js")
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadPluginDescriptor.next (<anonymous>)
 @ ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index.js (./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/loaders/styleguide-loader.js!./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index.js) 35:30-132
 @ ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index.js
 @ multi ./src/styles/tailwind.css ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index
./src/components/molecules/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.js
Error: [BABEL] /Users/vivz753/react-components/src/components/molecules/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.js: React Refresh Babel transform should only be enabled in development environment. Instead, the environment is: "production". If you want to override this check, pass {skipEnvCheck: true} as plugin options. (While processing: "/Users/vivz753/react-components/node_modules/react-refresh/babel.js")
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadPluginDescriptor.next (<anonymous>)
 @ ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index.js (./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/loaders/styleguide-loader.js!./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index.js) 44:30-145
 @ ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index.js
 @ multi ./src/styles/tailwind.css ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index
./src/components/molecules/PlaylistGeneratorButton/PlaylistGeneratorButton.js
Error: [BABEL] /Users/vivz753/react-components/src/components/molecules/PlaylistGeneratorButton/PlaylistGeneratorButton.js: React Refresh Babel transform should only be enabled in development environment. Instead, the environment is: "production". If you want to override this check, pass {skipEnvCheck: true} as plugin options. (While processing: "/Users/vivz753/react-components/node_modules/react-refresh/babel.js")
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadPluginDescriptor.next (<anonymous>)
 @ ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index.js (./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/loaders/styleguide-loader.js!./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index.js) 53:30-171
 @ ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index.js
 @ multi ./src/styles/tailwind.css ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/vivz753/react-components
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c styleguidist "build"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/vivz753/.npm/_logs/2021-03-15T05_03_20_188Z-debug.log
```

I was able to build without errors by running the command with the config from react-scripts like so
`npx styleguidist build --config ./node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`

I successfully deployed it onto Vercel here https://react-components-fho7l1ov3-discover-pom.vercel.app/
but none of my styles are displaying correctly and tailwindcss doesn't get applied

I've tried looking inside at the files in `./node_modules/@craco/craco/lib/features/webpack/babel.js` but I don't understand what the issue could be...

Inside `./node_modules/react-refresh/cjs/react-refresh-babel` shows the error that gets thrown, but I honestly have no idea why it's complaining

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  (function() {
'use strict';

function ReactFreshBabelPlugin (babel) {
  var opts = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : {};

  if (typeof babel.getEnv === 'function') {
    // Only available in Babel 7.
    var env = babel.getEnv();

    if (env !== 'development' && !opts.skipEnvCheck) {
      throw new Error('React Refresh Babel transform should only be enabled in development environment. ' + 'Instead, the environment is: "' + env + '". If you want to override this check, pass {skipEnvCheck: true} as plugin options.');
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer to your own question. This better indicates the question already has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

@carrotjuicelol figured it out. He had to use the prod version of craco's webpack config like so

```js
/* styleguide.config.js */
const path = require('path')

const { createWebpackDevConfig, createWebpackProdConfig } = require("@craco/craco");

const cracoConfig = require("./craco.config.js");
const webpackConfig = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? createWebpackProdConfig(cracoConfig) : createWebpackDevConfig(cracoConfig);

module.exports = {
  webpackConfig,
  require: [
    path.join(__dirname, './src/styles/tailwind.css')
  ]
}
```

`styleguidist build` now works perfectly.